# Issues Claiming A Business On Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to claim my business on Foursquare, but when I try to do it by phone both my main local number and main 800# are not working... It's telling me it is unable to verify that phone number?? These are the MAIN phone numbers?? If I try to mail verification, I need to somehow get it mailed to my PO Box (Breckenridge does not have physical mail delivery - ONLY Po Boxes), but when I try to either change the address entirely to the PO Box or just add the PO Box and hit the verify button, nothing happens. I've hit the verify button no less than a dozen times... Nothing. Please help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is in no way related to software development.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should file a ticket with Foursquare's support team:
http://support.foursquare.com/home

They should be able to help you!

Comment: Any chance finding ticket url